# результат перебора массива в html

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть проблемма, скорее это связано с руками и почти 20 часов без сна )
Перебор массива выводит результат и как бы все отлично, но...

```
foreach ($posts as $row) {
$sub_array = '';
$sub_array['ID'] = $row->ID;
$sub_array['title']= get_the_title($row->ID);
$sub_array['post_date'] = strftime("%A %d %B %Y",    strtotime($row->post_date));
$nposts[] = $sub_array;
}
```

Вот код разбора массива:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($nposts as $post){ 

if ($post['post_date'] != $last_date)
    {
    $html .= '<h3>'.$post['post_date'].'</h3>' ;
    } 

 $html .= '<div>id: ' . $post['ID'] . ' ' . $post['title'] . '</div><br>';
 $last_date = $post['post_date'];

};
echo $html;
```

В результате я получаю это:

```
<h3>Wednesday 24 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1475 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1455 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Tuesday 23 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1388 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1358 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1315 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1219 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 1198 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Monday 22 January 2018</h3>
<div>id: 1063 Title</div>
<br>
<div>id: 996 Title</div>
<br>

<h3>Wednesday 01 January 2014</h3>
<div>id: 959 Title</div>
<br>
```

Немного не то чего пытаюсь получить

Нужно так:

```
<div class="one">   
<h3>Wednesday 24 January 2018</h3>
        <div class="two">id: 1475 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1455 Title</div>

</div>

<div class="one">   
    <h3>Tuesday 23 January 2018</h3>
        <div class="two">id: 1388 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1358 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1315 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1219 Title</div>

        <div class="two">id: 1198 Title</div>>

</div>

    ......
```

Уже пробовал пересобрать массив, цыкл и гавнокодить ) все не то..
Можете минуснуть вопрос если поможете

Comment: А ты попробуй сделать не через foreach,a через while цикл ??

Comment: так я писал там, выше, что цыкл пробовал.
Дело не в том что не пробовал, а в том что как не пробовал все через Ж. В церковь чтоли сходить ?!

Comment: скажи что такое $nposts ?

Comment: Обновил, $nposts  массив